# Outbound VPN is Blocked by a Physical Wall

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

**Background**

Consider my typical home network, consisting of a cable ISP and retail LinkSys WiFi router.

My iPhone automatically joins the WiFi network when it's in range. Installed on the iPhone is ProtonVPN, client software for a popular VPN provider.

The VPN client connects "on demand" and for the most part works flawlessly.

**Problem**

**All connections over the VPN fail when the iPhone is used from a particular room in my home**.

Using another VPN client (e.g. OpenVPN) or even a different VPN provider all together (e.g. BraveVPN) triggers the same problem.

**Analysis**

The room in question has a concrete wall in the router-facing direction, so naturally one would assume that the WiFi signal is having trouble penetrating the wall, and perhaps I need a range extender of some sort.

Except that, while standing in the room in question...

- The WiFi signal indicator shows full strength.
- Manually disabling the VPN allows full connectivity to resume.
- SpeedTest.net with VPN disabled shows 50ms latency, 80Mbps down, and
  10 Mbps up. The connection is totally solid from that room.

It's only when the VPN is connected (any VPN, not just ProtonVPN) that connectivity is hindered, and only in that one room.

I'm familiar with the idea of a firewall blocking outbound VPN connections, but this case is unusual insofar as the connection seems to be blocked by a *physical* wall.

**Any idea what would cause an odd problem like this to manifest and how one would fix it?**

**UPDATE: RESPONDING TO COMMENTS**

I'm in a large highrise condo so there are a *ton* of visible WiFi networks. Two of them are mine: `SSIDName` and `SSIDName-Guest`. It seems unlikely that someone else in the building would be using my exact same SSID(s) and password, but I suppose anything is possible. Shall I try changing the name and password?

I did notice that on the list of available WiFi networks shown on the iPhone, there's a comment next to my password-protected network that says, "Weak Security." I'm not using WEP. I'm using whatever the latest encryption scheme is that came with my four year old router and two year old phone.

A lot of weird/spooky/unexplainable stuff has plagued me in this particular high rise. For instance, when watching AppleTV, all of a sudden the show will freeze and I'll see Asian [alphanumeric] characters on the screen asking if someone else can connect, along with a confirmation code. Just weird stuff I shouldn't be seeing unless someone else were on my network. I have an unusually named SSID and strong password though. And my building is filled with retired people; Not exactly a high value target.

**UPDATE: PROBLEM RESOLVED, BUT NO REAL ANSWERS**

Turning off the WiFi guest network caused the problem to go away. There's no reason I can fathom why that would work. I've given up trying to understand the nature of the problem. Sometimes you just have to walk away, I suppose.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the same WiFi network in all rooms? Please [edit] your question to add this information, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: @bodo I was just about to ask the same question. If you are really connected to the SAME router/wifi there is no way in hell this can happen. There has to be another network (possibly with the same name and same password) in that room that (for the iPhone) is the preferred network and that blocks the VPN.

Comment: Edited with response to your comments.

Comment: Walls do not block VPNs. They either block all kinds of traffic indiscriminately or not at all.

Comment: @YippieMcSmashmouth In your edit I don't see a confirmation that you really checked that you are connected to the same SSID when you are in the different rooms. There might be a different WiFi where your device can connect to, maybe a public WiFi or a friend's one.

Comment: I can confirm the only network I was connected to was SSIDName when the problem manifests. Killing the companion network, SSIDName-Guest, solved the problem (see update) but I honestly have no idea why. :(